# How to set marks with event in tapku library for JSON data that contain start date and last date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, tapku

This is my JSON data

```
result=(
        {
        currentCheckIn = 1501678485000;
        firstCheckIn = 1501649015000;
        id = 1;
    },
        {
        currentCheckIn = 1501822548000;
        firstCheckIn = 1501822547000;
        id = 2;
    }
)
```

I called the method inside this function

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLRequest *)connection {

     [self calendarMonthView:self marksFromDate:startdate toDate:lastdate];
}
```

but I am getting an error that **"incompatible pointer types sending 'CalendarMonthViewController *' to parameters of type TKCalenderMonthView'"**

Please help me how to set marks based on JSON start and end date in **tapku** and how to set an event on that selected marks? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: could you please post the prototype of calendarMonthView function.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link your problem solution [here](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar):

limited range, you can define a start and an end to you calendar